# Automatically check parent when child is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

When any checkbox with class .child-term is checked, I automatically need to check the preceding checkbox with class .parent-term.

I only want to check the preceding .parent-term class not all the checkboxes that have .parent-class. Same goes for the .child-term class. Any checkbox with .child-term only affects the .parent-term above.

If the .parent-term class was checked from a .sub-term checkbox the .parent-term can remain checked when all the associated .sub-term boxes are unchecked.

I have tried various solutions, but I can't figure it out.

I started a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6y132wy8/1/).

```
<ul class="cpt-terms-checkbox">
    <li class="parent-term church" id="category-church"><input id="church"
    name="church" type="checkbox" value="church">Church</li>

    <li><small>Sub Categories:</small></li>

    <li class="child-term elder" id="category-elder"><input id="elder"
    name="elder" type="checkbox" value="elder">Elder</li>
    <li class="child-term interim-pastor" id="category-interim-pastor">
    <input id="interim-pastor" name="interim-pastor" type="checkbox" value=
    "interim-pastor">Interim Pastor</li>

    <li class="parent-term law-firm" id="category-law-firm"><input id=
    "law-firm" name="law-firm" type="checkbox" value="law-firm">Law
    Firm</li>

    <li><small>Sub Categories:</small></li>

    <li class="child-term attorney" id="category-attorney"><input id=
    "attorney" name="attorney" type="checkbox" value=
    "attorney">Attorney</li>
    <li class="child-term attorney" id="category-attorney"><input id=
    "attorney" name="attorney" type="checkbox" value=
    "attorney">Paralegal</li>
</ul>
```

Adding to Anoop Joshi's solution . . . I changed .parent() to .parents() so it would move up higher and for those who may run this in Wordpress I wrapped it in an anonymous function.

```
(function($) {
    $(".child-term :input").change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).parents().prevAll(".parent-term:first").find("input").prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Would love to see the duplicate post. I searched and could not find anything close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prevAll()` to get all the previous nodes with specified selector.

Then you can use the `:first` selector to get the immediate previous element

```
$(".child-term :input").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).parent().prevAll(".parent-term:first").find("input").prop("checked", true);
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLnazpzL/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it works and I learned something.

Comment: @Jason Glad to hear that..